# Microsoft Graph API upload driveitem without changing the document ID

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I would like to use Microsoft Graph API to download, edit and upload the document to the same location without changing the document ID.

From the [documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_uploadcontent), it appears that the drive ID will change:

> If successful, this method returns a driveItem object in the response body for the newly created file.

Does anyone know of a way to edit the contents of a drive item (docx, xlsx, pptx) without changing the ID of the doc?

Answer (score 1):

Generally the best option is to allow OneDrive to handle this for you. The [DriveItem](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/driveitem) object has two properties that you can leverage for this: `webUrl` and `webDavUrl`.

Navigating to the `webUrl` property will open that document in the browser. From here the user can opt to edit the document either directly in the browser (i.e. Excel Online) or through their local Office client (i.e. Excel 2016 for Windows).

The `webDavUrl` provides a URL that an Office client can open directly. Office will handle editing, saving, etc. directly against the file in OneDrive.

Regardless of the method you choose, both will provide in-place editing of documents on OneDrive. When documents edits are done in this manor, the file ID won't be altered.

UPDATE:

When you're *replacing an existing file*, the `DriveItem.Id` shouldn't change. For interactive editing scenarios I would still go with `webURL`. However, for a scenario like this where you need to make edits programmaticly without a user involved, this is absolutely a reasonable path to take.

Comment: I should have mentioned that I need to do this programmatically without any human involvement. Hence, the need for using graph API.

Comment: I would like to write a C# app that would download, edit and upload all files in a drive folder. My strict requirements are that the document IDs don't change. -- the reason for this is in my organization, there are a lot of people who have the share URLs for the files that I will be editing. I need to ensure those people can still point to the same document after it is edited by me.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to verify that the doc ID remains the same after you replace the file with the same name. Moreover, it creates a version history that you can revert back to.